# Should Docker release all memory when all containers are closed?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am debugging a possible memory leak in a web service I have running as a Docker network. The  service has a Javascript front end, [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/) REST API, [Dask](https://dask.org/) worker pool, the [spaCy](https://spacy.io/) natural language toolkit...the works. I see intermittent running-out-of memory problems and I'm trying to get a handle on what could be going on.

I can run this system on my laptop, a MacBook Pro with 16 GB of memory where I am using Docker Desktop. When there are no containers running, Activity Monitor shows com.docker.hyperkit using about 12 GB. Then I launch the Docker network, which ultimately runs 14 containers to house the various components. I perform a fairly large batch job in the Docker network. It runs for an hour, during which time com.docker.hyperkit's memory creeps up to around 18 GB. This is not surprising--this is a memory intensive service. But when I stop all the containers in the network, I would expect com.docker.hyperkit's memory usage to drop back to 12 GB. Instead it stays at 18 GB. The only way I can get it back to 12 GB is to restart the Docker Desktop.

Is this expected behavior? It looks like a memory leak in Docker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it should not release the memory, and yes it is expected behavior.

There is no way to run docker containers natively on MacOS, so you run them inside of a virtual machine. A VM gets memory assigned to it, which it assigns to processes running inside of that VM. When those processes inside of the VM exit, the resources are released back to the VM, but not back to the parent MacOS. That's just how VM's work, and the fact that it didn't take all of the memory up to the limit specified in the Docker preferences immediately on startup is an impressive feat itself.

The containers themselves are processes running within this VM, and they will release all of their memory back to the VM upon exit. If you run something like `docker run --rm busybox free` you'll likely see the memory being used and freed within the VM.

For more details on this, there's several extensive threads in the github issues. Most of the comments on these threads appear to be from users assuming MacOS is running containers, rather than a VM that runs containers. Even completely idle, that VM will use some resources to run the kernel, container runtime daemons, volume sharing code, port forwarding code, etc. There's a lot of magic under the covers to make docker not look like a VM to the user, so that you can just pass paths and connect to ports on the MacOS side. The most helpful comment in the thread to me is here: https://github.com/moby/hyperkit/issues/231#issuecomment-448416559